# Change 2 fields in the post depending on the 3rd field before save

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I have a custom content type called **cards**.

I have 3 custom meta fields called:

**my_cards_activity** (select field type; options 0 and 1)

**my_cards_user** (select type; many options)

**my_cards_datetime** (text field type; yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format)

When I press SAVE button I want to get the value of the `my_cards_activity` field (value can be 0 or 1) and if the value is 0 then change `my_cards_datetime` and `my_cards_user` to empty value and only after the change save it all. If it is 1 then do nothing.

How to do such before save thing? How should my code in functions.php look like?

Comment: Use the hook `save_post` see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metabox) for a ton of examples and put an `if` inside the function that do the save.

Comment: @G.M. How do I limit custom save_post function only for a certain content type? In my case `cards`?

Comment: @G.M. Should I use `add_filter` ? Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hook `save_post` and put an if inside the function that do the save after the 'normal' save meta fields routine.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'this_is_the_function_name' ); 

function this_is_the_function_name( $post_id ) { 

    // No auto saves 
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    // make sure the current user can edit the post 
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // assure the post type
    if ( ! get_post_type($post_id) == 'cards' ) return;

    // assure the data are sended by the form
    if (
       ! isset($_POST['my_cards_activity']) ||
       ! isset($_POST['my_cards_datetime']) || ! isset('my_cards_user')
    ) return;

    $activity = $_POST['my_cards_activity'];

    // and now the simply logic
    if ( $activity == 1 ) {
        $datetime = $_POST['my_cards_datetime'];
        $user = $_POST['my_cards_user'];
    } else {
        $datetime = '';
        $user = '';    
    }

    // save data as array
    $meta_data = compact("activity", "datetime", "user");
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'card_data', $meta_data);

    // if you want can save data as 3 different meta fields in this case
    // delete the previous 2 lines and uncommente the following
    // update_post_meta($post_id, 'card_activity', $activity);
    // update_post_meta($post_id, 'datetime', $datetime);
    // update_post_meta($post_id, 'user', $user);        

}
```

If in your metabox have you setted a nonce field check for it before save.

See **Codex** for:

- [save_post action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)
- [get_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type)
- [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: Hm for some reason everything works, except the update_post_meta() function. I have tried to save/upadet only one field `update_post_meta($post_id, 'datetime', $datetime);` to eliminate errors. But still it seems not be working. Do you know can I var_dump all the meta fields of a content type?

Comment: Function is correct. Maybe you have to chack the name of the inputs `<input name="LOOK HERE"` and see if they are equal to what is inside `$_POST['LOOK HERE']`. For var_dump, just `var_dump($var);` and then `wp_die();` to stop execution and let you read.

Comment: no if i print_r and die every variable before update_post_meta it shows everything correct, the 0 and 1 and the if condition too. The problem is that it's not saved for some reason ;(. $post_id is correct too. The only problem could be in the name of my metabox.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's working except for the datetime field, but that's the problem of a meta box plugin I am using http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111248/unable-to-save-datetime-custom-meta-field-using-update-post-meta-function