# Unable to save datetime custom meta field using update_post_meta() function

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

When I do something like this (in my plugin function inside WP admin):

```
$metaboxes = get_post_meta( $post_id );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($metaboxes);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

I get all my metaboxes info **except the datetime**.

Why is that? Where are they stored and how can I access them?

I am using this plugin http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/ to add custom meta fields to my content type like:

```
array(
  'name'  => 'Date and time:',
  'type'  => 'datetime',
  'id'    => "rw_datetime",
),
```

I want to save the `datetime` field if some other field has certain value using `save_post` function and this is not working for datetime for some reason:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_datetime', '2013-08-28 11:11' );
```

But something like this for a text field is working nice:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_some_textfield', 'This is working!' );
```

Why is that? Why it's not working for datetime and why it is working for other field types?

How can I grab the datetime value if I know the `$post_id` and then update this field using `update_post_meta()` function?

**UPDATE:**

Code of my save_post function:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'things_before_save' ); 

function things_before_save( $post_id ) { 

    // No auto saves 
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    // make sure the current user can edit the post 
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // assure the post type
    if ( ! get_post_type($post_id) == 'cards' ) return;

    // working
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_some_textfield', 'This is working!' );

    // not working ;(
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_datetime', '2013-08-28 11:11' );

}
```

Notice that I am not working with any variables, just with strings `This is working!` and `2013-08-28 11:11` to eliminate possible errors.

So, I guess the problem is that rw_datetime is stored somewhere else and not at the same place as other metaboxes.

Comment: Please can you post your code? Have you checked your post meta table?

Comment: @iEmanuele I have updated my question with the code. Please, check it now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you're using that plugin in a wrong way. It's not necessary hook to `save_post` because the plugin do it for you. Simply register your meta box and your fields. To retrieve the values check [this](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/helper-function-to-get-meta-value/)

Comment: things_before_save = I need to make some changes in the save process depending on other things. I have just simplified stuff to not make it more complicated. Please, chcek this post for more details on my situation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111173/change-2-fields-in-the-post-depending-on-the-3rd-field-before-save It describes the reason why I need to make another function using save_post. The question is mostly solved, but I am stuck on the saving of the datetime field. Other fields can be saved without a problem.

Comment: @Derfder the question you linked, answered by me, do not takes into account the plugin you used. (In that question you don't say anything about any plugin) I don't know that plugin, my function is intended to work without plugins. Maybe problem is there.

Comment: @G.M. Ok, I will tick your answer as solved ;). It's probably caused by that plugin.